# Vim keeps resetting textwidth to 0, why?

Tags: vim

I am trying to understand why VIM keeps resetting my textwidth to 0.

To create the problem, I open a new file in Vim, and I type:

```
:set textwidth=72
```

I then enter a sentenace or two and I can see that it's ensuring the width of the text never goes beyond 72 characters.  All good.  The problem comes about, when I save the docment using the bellow command, and then when I re-open the file the setwidth is reset to 0.

```
:wq!
```

So if I re-open this file now, the text width is set back to zero.  I confirm by typing:

```
: set textwidth?
```

And the result is 0.  This is incredibly annoying.  How to I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please don’t add the answer to your question. If you feel the answer needs additional details, edit that instead (I did it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't keep your settings between sections like that.

You have to build a .vimrc config file (in your home directory) and add the settings you want, this way each time Vim loads it includes the settings from the config file:

```
cat >> .vimrc << EOF
set textwidth=72
EOF
```

Comment: This immediately solved my problem.

Comment: Annoyingly this seems to have bust my colour theme.  My comment colours were a particular colour and i cant remember how i set it.  How do i restore the colours i was using, do you know?

Comment: You would have to read up on the VIM config that's missing. If I had to guess, maybe you need to add "syntax on" into the config. And you could add "set number". But if you are downloading a color scheme you'll have to put that into the ~/.vim/colors from the look of it. I can't help more than that, as I haven't played around with that feature within VIM.